# Port ArrayList of java into C#

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin

I am developing for android in C# using Xamarin.Android. I am trying to port some code of Java into C#. during this I came across ArrayList Of Line class. like

```
ArrayList<Line> linesCollection = new ArrayList<Line>();
```

I am not sure How can I port this in C# ?

`My main problem is Line Class how can I get it in Xamarin.Android ?`

Any help is appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: What about the Line Class ?

Comment: `List<Line> linesCollection = new List<Line>();`

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
List<Line> linesCollection = new List<Line>();
```

The Line is a interface in Java. In C# i can find the ITextViewLine interface, but I am not sure if this is the same. You can take a look at it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.text.formatting.itextviewline.aspx

If this is what you need, than u can make a class that inherits from this interface.

Answer (score 1):

Following Java dcumentation [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) is :

> Resizable-array implementation of the List interface.

Resizable, with allow random access data structure. 
The correposnding data structure in C# is [List of T](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx)

So your code may look pretty much like:

```
var lines = new List<Line>();
```

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko: thanks, that was occasional C++11 influence :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`List`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) class in c#

```
List<Line> linesCollection = new List<Line>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry guys Actually It is my mistake. I am trying to port JustifyTextView code in java form [**From Here**](https://github.com/merterhk/JustifiedTextView/blob/master/JustifiedTextView.java)

In the FirstLine I Found

```
ArrayList<Line> linesCollection = new ArrayList<Line>();
```

I thought that Here `Line` Class is from `Java or android`. But actually It is a custom class below in the code.
Like -

```
class Line {
        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
        float spacing = 15f;

        public Line() {
        }

        public Line(ArrayList<String> words, float spacing) {
            this.words = words;
            this.spacing = spacing;
        }

        public void setSpacing(float spacing) {
            this.spacing = spacing;
        }

        public float getSpacing() {
            return spacing;
        }

        public void addWord(String s) {
            words.add(s);
        }

        public ArrayList<String> getWords() {
            return words;
        }
    }
```

I admit my mistake :) Thanks everybody for answer.